# MySQL Router 8.0.19 bootstrapping fails due to missing privileges

Tags: mysql

Following the [MySQL Router documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/mysqlrouter.html) I'm getting the following error bootstrapping the router. Both cluster and router versions are 8.0.19.

```
Error: Error creating MySQL account for router (GRANTs stage): 
Error executing MySQL query "GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.* 
TO 'mysql_router5_vl2j3rlcnec9'@'%'": Access denied for user 'runtime'@'%' to database
'mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata' (1044)
```

It seems something is missing to bootstrap the router successfully, but what exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is incomplete: the **EXECUTE** privilege is missing, as well as **SELECT** privilege on performance_schema.global_variables.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.* TO
'bootstrapuser'@'%';

GRANT SELECT ON performance_schema.global_variables TO 'bootstrapuser'@'%';
```

Credit goes to:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-mysql-router/+bug/1861234

Comment: Opened a bug to update the docs: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98575